# Regex parsing of DNS answer

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I would like to parse the following lines

```
8.8.19.12.53 > 125.15.15.9.40583: [udp sum ok] 62639 q: A? mp.microsoft.com. 6/5/9 mp.microsoft.com. CNAME .mp.microsoft.com.c.footprint.net., mp.microsoft.com.c.footprint.net. A 8.250.143.254, mp.microsoft.com.c.footprint.net. A 8.250.157.254 ns: c.footprint.net. NS d.ns.c.footprint.net. ar: d.ns.c.footprint.net. A 4.26.235.155 (439)
8.8.19.12.53 > 125.15.15.9.42091: [udp sum ok] 46555 q: A? www.toto.net. 1/0/0 www.toto.net. A 120.33.1.11 (47)
```

and  get the following output

```
125.15.15.9 mp.microsoft.com A 8.250.143.254 A 8.250.157.254
125.15.15.9 www.toto.net A 120.33.1.11
```

I succeeded in parsing the first two fields with command

```
sed -Eun 's/[^>]+> ([0-9.]+)\.[0-9]+:.+q: A\? ([a-z0-9.-]+)\.([^:]+).*/\1:\2:\3/pg
```

`

But I cannot get the resolved IPs (A xx.xx.xx.xx). In fact there may be several.

Would it be possible to get such output using sed or Perl ?

**EDIT**:
As I added in comments, parsing of a larger input sample, I also require several lines to be discarded in the output. This lines can be characterized by :

- the number of A records ("A xx.xx.xx.xx") is non null
- or the line must not contains `NXDomain\*?-`

I succeed in meeting the new first need, but not for the second.

Following the @ikegami reply, here is my attempt:

```
  perl -nle '
     my $field_value_re = qr/(?![^\s:]++:(?!\S)) \S++ (?: (?! \s++ [^\s:]++:(?!\S) ) \s++ \S++ )*+/x;

     my ($id, $rest) = /^ \s+ ( [^:]++ ) : \s++ $field_value_re ( .* ) /sx
        or next;

     my ($ip) = $id =~ /^ \S++ \s++ \S++ \s++ ( [^\s\.]++\.[^\s\.]++\.[^\s\.]++\.[^\s\.]++ )\.[^\s\.]++ \z /x
        or next;

     my %fields = $rest =~ /\G \s++ ( [^\s:]++ ) :(?!\S) \s++ ( $field_value_re ) /gsx;

     my ($query, $answers) = $fields{q} =~ /^ A\? \s++ ( \S++ ) \s++ \S++ \s++ ( .* ) /sx
        or next;

     $query =~ s/\.\z//;

     my @answers = split(/\s*+,\s*+/, $answers);
     my ($afield) = join " ", map { /^\S++\s++A\s++(\S++)/ } @answers;
     if ( length($afield) != 0)
     {
             print join " ", $ip, $query, $afield;
     }
  ' dns.sample
```

Comment: I have edited your question to try to understand it. Is the incoming data really on only two lines?

Comment: I upvoted as countermeasures

Comment: @Borodin. Thank you for your edits. The provided incoming data is extracted from a stream. These have been selected to be a representative sample of input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each line appears to be of the form

```
{"id" with spaces}: {stuff} [ {key}: {stuff} ]*
```

You appear to be interested in information inside the "id", and inside the field named `q`. The value of the `q` field appears to be of the form

```
A? {word} {word} {ns_return} [, {ns_return} ]*
```

Here's a robust solution that handles the format described above.

```
perl -nle'
   my $field_value_re = qr/(?![^\s:]++:(?!\S)) \S++ (?: (?! \s++ [^\s:]++:(?!\S) ) \s++ \S++ )*+/x;

   my ($id, $id_val, $rest) = /^ ( [^:]++ ) : \s++ ( $field_value_re ) ( .* ) /sx
      or next;

   next if $id_val =~ /\bNXDomain\b/;

   my ($ip) = $id =~ /^ \S++ \s++ \S++ \s++ ( [^\s\.]++\.[^\s\.]++\.[^\s\.]++\.[^\s\.]++ )\.[^\s\.]++ \z /x
      or next;

   my %fields = $rest =~ /\G \s++ ( [^\s:]++ ) :(?!\S) \s++ ( $field_value_re ) /gsx;

   my ($query, $answers) = $fields{q} =~ /^ A\? \s++ ( \S++ ) \s++ \S++ \s++ ( .* ) /sx
      or next;

   $query =~ s/\.\z//;

   my @answers =
      map { /^\S++\s++A\s++(\S++)/ }
         split(/\s*+,\s*+/, $answers);

   next if !@answers;

   print join " ", $ip, $query, map { "A $_" } @answers;
' log
125.15.15.9 mp.microsoft.com A 8.250.143.254 A 8.250.157.254
125.15.15.9 www.toto.net A 120.33.1.11
```

Comment: I just ran on a larger input sample (500k  lines) and I found a case that was not included in the description. Would it be possible to discard lines matching `NXDomain\*?-? q:` ?

Comment: Sorry I add one more case : I also would like to discard lines with no returned IP record (A xx.xx.xx.xx). I know this is possible with post processing treatment (`grep -v` and `awk`).

Comment: I wrote the code so it's easy to make such changes, and you announced you upvoted someone specifically for making it hard for you. Then, you don't even make an attempt to make the change yourself? That's pretty insulting.

Comment: I didn't mean to insult you. I upvoted other replies because they meet my initial need. However I chose your reply as the source of my script, as it is pretty clear compared to the other, even if I do not understand all details. That's why I added two more queries (comments) to your reply and not to all replies. Moreover, your code may seem simple to you, although this is not the case for me. I tried few hours (and still trying) to modify your code to fit all my need with regex101 without success. In fact I'm not familiar with such complex regex.

Comment: I didn't say the code was simple; I said the changes was simple (because I already did the complex job of parsing your text). I see you still haven't made an attempt.

Comment: Changes are simple for you. Even the ` field_value_re` is incomprehensible for me. However I guess that this is the part I should modify to meet my first new need. I grope for ways to achieve it.

Comment: No, the changes are simple, period. /// Again, it doesn't matter that `field_value_re` is incompresensible; you just need to know it matches the field value. /// Again, you should not be modifying that at all.

Comment: The only regex change that was needed was the addition of a capture. Now, I've even done that for you.

Comment: All you needed to add was `next if $id_val =~ /\bNXDomain\b/;` and `next if !@answers;`. Like I said, the necessary change was elementary.

Answer (score 3):

This does as you ask with the sample data

I first build a regex pattern `$url_re` that matches numeric URLs to make the following code more concise. Then I search for the first URL immediately after `>`, the named URL right after `A?`, and all of the following URLs which are preceded by `A`

They are all stored in array `@urls` and printed

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.010;

my $url_re = qr/(?:\d+\.){3}\d+/;

while ( <DATA> ) {

    my @urls = ( />\s+($url_re)/, /A\?\s+([-\w.]+\w)/, /(A\s+$url_re)/g );

    say "@urls";
}

__DATA__
8.8.19.12.53 > 125.15.15.9.40583: [udp sum ok] 62639 q: A? mp.microsoft.com. 6/5/9 mp.microsoft.com. CNAME .mp.microsoft.com.c.footprint.net., mp.microsoft.com.c.footprint.net. A 8.250.143.254, mp.microsoft.com.c.footprint.net. A 8.250.157.254 ns: c.footprint.net. NS d.ns.c.footprint.net. ar: d.ns.c.footprint.net. A 4.26.235.155 (439)
8.8.19.12.53 > 125.15.15.9.42091: [udp sum ok] 46555 q: A? www.toto.net. 1/0/0 www.toto.net. A 120.33.1.11 (47)
```

#### output

```
125.15.15.9 mp.microsoft.com A 8.250.143.254 A 8.250.157.254 A 4.26.235.155
125.15.15.9 www.toto.net A 120.33.1.11
```

Answer (score 1):

This prints the desired output by using the `map` function in a somewhat unorthodox way to ignore any fields after `q:`

```
perl -lne 'print join qq/\t/, m/> ([\d\.]+)\./, map {/A\? ([^\s]+)\./, /(A [\d\.]+)/g} / q:([^:]+)/' log.txt
```

Comment: @ikegami OK well, I fixed it by confining the second and third regexes to the `q:` field, as you pointed out in your answer. it's ugly but it should work.

Comment: The difference with the desired output is that the **/(A [\d\.]+)/g** should stop after matching a potential "ns:" field

Comment: @vera yup fixed now

Comment: @vera, Why would you reward fragility and lack of maintainability?! (Worse, the OP already wants two changes!)

Comment: I didn't claim this is the superior answer, it's just one of many possible answers. I defer to @ikegami on what is fragile and maintainable

Comment: it would perhaps be helpful to explain why you say that though.